# SQLite Visual Studio Linker Errors

Tags: c++, windows, sqlite, mobile, linker-errors

I have 2 C++ projects, one for Windows XP/Vista/7 (WinXP) and the other is for Windows Mobile 6 (WinMo). Both projects use the same source code.

I am trying to link against sqlite3.lib. I have generated this file using the lib tool that comes with VS and the sqlite.def file. I added this file to the Resource folder of both projects using Add -> Existing Item.... I also added it in Additional Dependencies (Configuration Properties > Linker > Input). I also placed the sqlite3.dll file in the working and executable directories.

I wrote some code and the class that uses sqlite3 has #include "sqlite3.h".

Now, in the WinXP project, I am able to compile, link and perform database ops using the sqlite3 API. In the WinMo project, I can compile, but get linker errors for all the functions from the sqlite3 library I need:

```
1>Linking...
1>SQLiteDatabase.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol sqlite3_shutdown      referenced in function "public: virtual __cdecl...
....
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need the .lib file, not the .obj file.

You are using the .obj file, you got that file from

> > Visual Studio 2010\Projects\projectname\projectname\Release

You need to get the .lib file with the same name from

> > Visual Studio 2010\Projects\projectname\Release

Does that make sense? Go back two folders, then go into the Release folder. Inside that release folder there will be the .lib file.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have the latest version of sqlite, and `sqlite3_shutdown` is supported on both platforms.

I found [this](http://www.sqlitening.com/support/index.php?topic=3200.0).